# Restore missing data after mySQL repair operation?

Tags: mysql

Our database became corrupt after a server restart so we ran a repair on all tables but we're now missing random pockets of data across all tables. When mySQL repair runs, does it back up the bad data before it is removed? Is there any other way to see what was deleted from the tables and restore it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only option is to restore a previous backup.
MySQL repair does not backup any data, in fact the manual recommends [you create a backup before running the repair.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/repair-table.html)

> Caution
>   Make a backup of a table before performing a table repair operation; under some circumstances the operation might cause data loss. Possible causes include but are not limited to file system errors. See Chapter 8, Backup and Recovery.

You can either restore the backup and run from the backup, or restore the backup next to your now repaired table, and [compare the data manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/compare-differences-between-two-tables-in-mysql).

Comment: Damn I was afraid you might say that. We'll know for next time. Thank you